# Consider the field $F=Z_3$, with elements denoted [0],[1],[2], and the vector space $V=F^2$ over $F$, with elements denoted as pairs ([i],[j]).

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the field $F=\mathbb Z_3$, with elements denoted $[0],[1],[2]$, and the vector space $V=F^2$ over $F$, with elements denoted as pairs $([i],[j])$.

List all proper subspaces $W\subset V$, where `proper' means $W\neq V$. For example, you might describe the subspaces by listing all their elements. Give a brief justification of why your list is complete.

I'm confused about this question. How do I list all the proper subspaces? There are two many subsets there. Or did I just misunderstand the question?

Comment: how is $F_2$ vector space over $F$

Comment: @user345777 -- I'm sure $F^2$ is meant.

Answer (score 2):

$V$ is a two dimensional vectorspace over $F$. Therefore, all proper subspaces must have dimension strictly less than 2.

The zero dimensional subspace is trivially just $\{([0],[0])\}$.

The one dimensional subspaces are the subspaces spanned by a single vector. Since $F$ is finite, we can write all of these subspaces explicitly.

Let's start with the vector $([0],[1])$. We can compute the span of this vector since we are able to write every scalar in $F$. Therefore, the vectorspace spanned by $([0],[1])$ is,
$$ \{ [0]([0],[1]), [1]([0],[1]), [2]([0],[1]) \}
= \{([0],[0]), ([0],[1]), ([0],[2]) \} $$

Now repeat this process with every vector in $V$. You will note that some of these spaces will turn out to be the same. For example, the space spanned by $([0],[2])$ is the same as that spanned by $([0],[1])$.